# Installed smart switch but nearby circuit keeps breaking

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, neutral

I just installed a smart switch (Leviton Decora) in my garage and the switch works fine. But I soon noticed that the circuit controlling outlets in the closest room to the garage keeps breaking. I think it has something to do with the neutral bundle.

The original wiring included three bundled neutral wires. The smart switch did not come with a pigtail but I bought a 14 gauge wire at Lowes, added it to the bundle and connected the other end to the smart switch. As I mentioned, the switch works fine but I’m wondering if adding the new neutral to the bundle could have created an overload that’s affecting the circuit in the neighboring room. Thoughts?

[image: image is of one side of the new smart switch. The other black wire is attached on opposite side]

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer, but I tried to reposition the wires for a better fit inside the box. Possible that the ground was touching one of the live terminals on the other dumb switch inside the box. I’m not sure why/if that would cause a completely separate circuit in another room to break, instead of the circuit where the contact was taking place. Anyway, Seems to be working fine with no circuit breaking right now. But if anyone has other ideas, please share.

Comment: Is the other room's breaker (the one that keeps tripping) a GFCI or AFCI? Does it have a "test" button on it?